# Custom filename for generated file in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

In my `_config.yml` file I have defined the *permalink* like `permalink: /posts/:title/` (notice the ending slash).

For a post in `_posts/my_first_post/2017-05-06-my_first_post.markdown` the generated file is `_site/posts/my_first_post/index.html`.

How can I change the filename from `index.html` to something arbitrary like `something.htm`?

Edit 1:

Didn't want to do this, but I ultimately had to look at the Jekyll source code:

In the `lib/jekyll/page.rb` there is this:

```
def destination(dest)
  path = site.in_dest_dir(dest, URL.unescape_path(url))
  path = File.join(path, "index") if url.end_with?("/")
  path << output_ext unless path.end_with? output_ext
  path
end
```

And in `lib/jekyll/document.rb` there is this:

```
def destination(base_directory)
  dest = site.in_dest_dir(base_directory)
  path = site.in_dest_dir(dest, URL.unescape_path(url))
  if url.end_with? "/"
    path = File.join(path, "index.html")
  else
    path << output_ext unless path.end_with? output_ext
  end
  path
end
```

So the *index.html* part is hardcoded. This question cannot be answered...unless there is a plugin that does what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a plugin and monkey patch those classes

---

Create `_plugins/_my_custom_index.rb`

```
module Jekyll
  class Page    
    def destination(dest)
      path = site.in_dest_dir(dest, URL.unescape_path(url))
      path = File.join(path, "index") if url.end_with?("/")
      path << output_ext unless path.end_with? output_ext

      # replace index with title
      path.sub! 'index',  data['title'] if data['title']
      path
    end
  end
end

module Jekyll
  class Document
    def destination(base_directory)
      dest = site.in_dest_dir(base_directory)
      path = site.in_dest_dir(dest, URL.unescape_path(url))
      if url.end_with? "/"
        path = File.join(path, "index.html")
      else
        path << output_ext unless path.end_with? output_ext
      end

      # replace index with title
      path.sub! 'index',  data['title'] if data['title']

      path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: nice tip ut not maintainable... i needed to use a different file naming at _post directory and ended up using symlinks...

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the code of Jekyll to your specific requirement.

Open `lib\jekyll\Page.rb` in jekyll folder and update the destination method:

```
module Jekyll
  class Page
    def destination(dest)
      path = site.in_dest_dir(dest, URL.unescape_path(url))
      path = File.join(path, "index") if url.end_with?("/")
      path << output_ext unless path.end_with? output_ext

      # replace index with title
      path.sub! 'index',  data['title'] if data['title']

      path
    end
  end
end
```

Also update the `destination` method in `lib\jekyll\Document.rb` with the same line before returning `path`

Comment: While this would obviously work, it is not a scalable solution, especially for continuous deployment. A plugin would be an acceptable solution in this case.

Comment: Well, creating a plugin is simple - see the new answer.

Comment: I have actually managed to adjust my other dependents to work with `index.html`, but I'm awarding the effort in this case, since I'm pretty sure this is the best answer for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You can change to permalink `/posts/:title/:title.html`

However, the post will be now accessible via `http://server/post/my_first_post/my_first_post.html`

If you want to change the default behavior, you should modify Jekyll.Page.destination

Comment: This will not do for me, the url must remain as it is. Only the `index.html` filename needs to be changed.

Comment: If you change the `index.html` file then your server will not be able to serve `/posts/:title/` since it point to a directory instead of an actual web page within the directory - In those cases , The server will serve the default page -  `index.html`.

Comment: You are, of course, referring to the default behaviour, which is not the case in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `permalink: /posts/:title/something:output_ext` in the `_config.yml` or in post front matter

Comment: This will not do for me, the url **must remain as it is**. Only the `index.html` filename needs to be changed. Your solution results in the links to contain the `something:output_ext` which I do not want. Basically I want control over the naming of `index.html` in the exact situation described above. As it is right now, Jekyll assumes that the filename should be `index.html`, which might not always be a good default and should somehow be configurable.

Comment: @Interfector this will produce `/posts/welcome-to-jekyll/something.html` because   `:output_ext` is VARIABLE will give you  `.html` extension and add it something to become `something.html`

Comment: I know the reason, but what I am looking for is a solution to my problem. I have added an EDIT to my question which should shed some light.